# Sending a login event from server to client

Tags: node.js, events, express, websocket

I am trying to set up a chat interface on a site using nodejs.
I need to update the logged_in_user list after a user is authenticated.
I am using this code as a reference

https://github.com/amirrajan/nodejs-chat

```
io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('sendchat', (data) => {
    io.sockets.emit('updatechat', socket.username, data);
  });
```

As you can see on the 'connection' event the updatechat event is triggered.
In the client side (public/app.js),the chatlist is updated on getting the updatechat event.

I need to do the same but after a client is authenticated.
Can I somehow tweak the socket object to trigger the event on a 'login' event

This is my code

```
app.get('/authenticate',function(request,response)
                {
                var db = couch.db.use('users');
                var email = request.query['email'];
                var pass = request.query['password'];
                db.get(email,{email:email},function(err,body){
                                if(err)
                                console.log(err);
                                else
                                {

                                var user_pass = body['password'];
                                var name = body['name'];
                                console.log(user_pass);
                                if(pass == user_pass)
                                {

                eventEmitter.emit('login',name);
                response.render('pages/dashboard',{user:body['name']});
                                }
                } 
                });

// And on 'login' event
eventEmitter.on('login', function(name)
                {

                // ?????? Broadcast the new user to all logged in users to update the chatlist
                });
```

I have tried to redirect the logged in users to another port and use the socket 'connection' event there.It sort of works but I want to know if there is another approach I could use.

Comment: How do you authenticate? Using Ajax or normal full page load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use socket.io middleware for authentication.

```
  io.use(function(socket,next){
        //auth here
  });
```

Take a look at the docs http://socket.io/docs/server-api/

You can get the req and res objects from the socket object being passed to the middleware.

Note, it is not a great idea to pass a password on the query since the url is not pass ssl.